# Uniform convergence and boundedness for the sequence of functions $\{f_{n}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum, sequence-of-function

For $n \geq 1$, let $f_{n}(x) = x e^{-nx^2}$, $x \in \Bbb{R}$; Then the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ is Uniformly convergent on $\Bbb{R}$?.

I did this $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for each $x \in \Bbb{R}$.

I now check for $\| f_{n} - f\| = \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| = \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_{n}(x)  - 0| = \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}} |f_{n}(x)|$.

Maximum for $f_{n}(x)$ occurs at $x = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$ whose value is $\frac{e^{-\frac{n}{2}}}{\sqrt{2n}}$.

and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{n}{2}}}{\sqrt{2n}} \rightarrow 0$.

So I think $\{f_{n}\}$ is Uniformly convergent.

Now is the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ bounded? and is it only uniformly convergent on the compact subsets of $\Bbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

What you've proved is that, in effect, $d_\infty(f_n,f) \to 0$ in the whole real line (in particular this works for each subset of $\mathbb{R}$, compact or not). As for boundedness, since

$$
d_\infty(f_n,f_m) \leq d_\infty(f_n,f) + d_\infty(f,f_m)
$$

By convergence, there exists $k \geq 1$ such that $d_\infty(f_j,f) \leq 1$ when $j \geq k$. Hence if

$$
M = max\{d_\infty(f_1,f)\dots d_\infty(f_k,f), 1\}
$$

we have that $d_\infty(f_n,f_m) \leq 2M$. Note also that this same argument proves that in any metric space, convergent sequences are bounded.